# FormDigest from SharePoint online return unauthorized error

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, unauthorized

I am trying to get the FormDigest from SharePoint online. I am using credentials which are working when I login to SharePoint site. However, when I connect to SharePoint via C#, it gives *

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

error.
Below is the code for the same.

```
public static string GetFormDigest()
        {
            string formDigest = null;
            try
            {
                const string RESTURL = "{0}/_api/contextinfo";
                string restUrl = string.Format(RESTURL, sharepointUrl);
                HttpWebRequest wreq = HttpWebRequest.Create(restUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

                var securePassword = new SecureString();
                //Convert string to secure string  
                foreach (char c in password)
                    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                securePassword.MakeReadOnly();

                var creds = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securePassword);

                wreq.Credentials = creds;
                wreq.Method = "POST";
                wreq.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
                wreq.ContentLength = 0;
                wreq.ContentType = "application/json";
                wreq.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
                wreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)";
                WebResponse wresp = wreq.GetResponse();

                string result;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wresp.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }

                var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var val = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(result);
                var d = val["d"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
                var wi = d["GetContextWebInformation"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
                formDigest = wi["FormDigestValue"].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
            return formDigest;

        }
```

**METHOD #2**

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("<<SharePointURL>>"))
                {
                    var securedPassword = GetSecuredPassword();
                    // SharePoint Online Credentials  
                    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securedPassword);
                    // Get the SharePoint web  
                    Web web = clientContext.Web;
                    // Load the Web properties  
                    clientContext.Load(web);
                    // Execute the query to the server.  
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    // Web properties - Display the Title and URL for the web  
                    Console.WriteLine("Title: " + web.Title + "; URL: " + web.Url);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
```

**METHOD #3**

```
public static async void GetDigest()
        {
            try
            {
                const string RESTURL = "{0}/_api/contextinfo";
                string restUrl = string.Format(RESTURL, sharepointUrl);
                var uri = new Uri(restUrl);
                var credentialsCache = new CredentialCache
                    {{uri, "NTLM", new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain)}};
                var handler = new HttpClientHandler {Credentials = credentialsCache};
                var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler) {BaseAddress = uri};
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "text/xml");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("DataServiceVersion", "3.0");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Host", "helenoy.sharepoint.com");
                ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(uri).ConnectionLeaseTimeout =
                    120 * 1000; // Close connection after two minutes
                var response = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, null).Result;
                string respdata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(respdata);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is there any reason you don't use SharePoint's own client libraries? All this code is unnecessary - HttpWebRequest has been replaced by HttpClient, JavaScriptSerializer is replaced by Json.NET.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You're trying to authenticate to do what? Make an OData query? Retrieve some list items?

Comment: BTW if you [check the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard) you'll see that you can't use Basic Authentication any more. SharePoint Online, like any other cloud service, requires an access token. In this case it's an OAuth token.

Comment: Updated other tried methods.

Comment: What is the question? What are you trying to do? Why aren't you doing what the docs show? Trying to do the same wrong thing in slightly different ways won't work any better. I do see several extra bugs though like `httpClient.PostAsync(uri, null).Result`

Comment: In fact, the only thing that could work was #2 - using CSOM. As the docs explain though, you need to use an OAuth token, not a username/password combination. If #2 fails, you need to see why it fails, not assume that CSOM is broken and thousands of developers haven't noticed it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am trying to connect to SharePoint online and get the FormDigest for next operation via a console application. I have the user name and password which is working directly on SharePoint.

Comment: If you can't get your code to work with HttpClient, why assume HttpClient is broken? In that case you're assuming that  *every .NET developer* hasn't noticed that HttpClient isn't working. In fact, in .NET Core HttpWebRequest is nothing but a legacy adapter over HttpClient

Comment: Yes, and SharePoint Online is NOT using that authentication method. The docs explain that the *old library only* used it. The *new* CSOM library works with OAuth. I wouldn't be surprised if basic auth was disabled at some point. In fact, on-prem SharePoint IS NOT BUILT to work like this. It's built to use Windows Authentication. If you have to use basic authentication with an on-prem installation something is very, very wrong

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos did I mentioned that HttpClient is broken? It is not about .net. BTW, I am not a SharePoint developer. I am a MS Dynamics CRM developer. Trying to integrated CRM with SharePoint online.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230747/discussion-between-vijay-balkawade-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: Read the docs. You can't force SharePoint Online to change how it works. Or Dynamics - Dynamics is a cloud-first product now, using Azure AD as the primary authentication mechanism. If the docs say you need OAuth, you can't keep trying to use basic authentication. If you want to integrate on-prem and cloud Dynamics/Office services, you need to do so at the AD level.